# Azure Table entity name change

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I just **modified** the name of the property of the table on Azure.  And it reflected as totally **new** property, which makes sense.  My question is, is there a way to change property name  on Azure Table without iterate each record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, each entity is it's own set of property names and values.  There is really no such thing as a 'table property' in the same sense that you think of a column in an RDBMS table.  Most storage explorer tools iterate through the entities and build a collection of all of the properties for each entity and then display those as 'columns' which is why it looks like the properties are related to the table itself.  If you want to change the property names of existing entities then you need to iterate through each entity and change it.